# How to manage mouseevent on position absolute div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm working with Angula, and I'm developing a timeline. For this reason I'm using angular-resizable-element library to manual resize a div. I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="timeline" style="min-height=800px; min-width: 1000px; position: relative">
  <div class="container" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; ">
    <div data-date="01/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="02/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="03/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="04/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="05/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="06/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="07/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="08/02/2023"></div>
  </div>
  <div mwlResizable (resizing)="onResize($event)" (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)"></div>
</div>
```

When I'm resizing the div "mwlResizable" I would use the mousemove event to get the cursor position on the div with "container" class (that is expanded over his parent) and get the relative "data-date" attribute value. I added this eventListener:

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
  if (event.target.getAttribute('data-date')) {
    const dateValue = event.target.getAttribute('data-date');
    console.log(dateValue);
  }
});
```

This works correctly only if I move the mouse outside the div mwlResizable, but when I'm resizing the div nothing happens. I think it could depends on position absolute that I set on container div. Is there a way to trigger the events also if there is a div with position relative over the div with position absolute?

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work. Here I am removing the **position: absoulute** form the child div element and adding it to resize handle elements.

HTML Code

```html
<div
  style="min-height: 300px;min-width: 300px;position: relative;background: red;" mwlResizable [enableGhostResize]="true"
  (resizing)="onResize($event)" (resizeEnd)="onResizeEnd($event)"
  (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)"
>
  <div style="position: absolute;height: 5px;cursor: row-resize;width: 100%;top: 0;" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ top: true }"></div>
  <div style="position: absolute;height: 100%;cursor: col-resize;width: 5px;left: 0;" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ left: true }"></div>
  <div style="position: absolute;height: 5px;cursor: row-resize;width: 100%;right: 0;" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ right: true }"></div>
  <div style="position: absolute;height: 100%;cursor: col-resize;width: 5px;bottom: 0;" mwlResizeHandle [resizeEdges]="{ bottom: true }"></div>
  <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;top: 0;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0;">
    <div data-date="01/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="02/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="03/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="04/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="05/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="06/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="07/02/2023"></div>
    <div data-date="08/02/2023"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS Code

```js
  onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  onResize($event: any): void {
    console.log('onResize', $event);
  }

  onResizeEnd($event: any): void {
    console.log('onResizeEnd', $event);
  }
```

You can use paste above code in your HTML and TS file.
Here we are using **(mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)"** to track mouse event of the box.
Here in the below SS you can see the mouse event on console screen when I am hovering on red box. And this red box is resizable.
Hope this will solve your problem.